# What's the difference between built in groups vs custom groups

Tags: groups

Are there any big difference between built in groups (like, approvers, designer, Site Collection Resources members, owners, etc.) and custom groups (like I created using SP gui. Sales-Marketing, Sales-Approvers, Sales-VP)

I have "Anyone can view this group checked". I am trying to get all the users in a group so I am using this web services _vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx and GetUserCollectionFromGroup method. When I use Approvers or other build in group it works. If I use a custom group then I get error.

Please suggest.

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have at least 4 different post on this topic with exactly same issue. I just used the web services tool to verify your issue and you are 100%. I am getting result. I truly wish to find an answer this time.

Comment: could you paste in the error message as part of the post?

Comment: Here is the error ... http://www.filefactory.com/file/1kd33bcgxb0n/n/WebServiceError_txt

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no difference between built-in and SharePoint Groups. Are you able to view group members with the same account using the SharePoint User Interface?
What is the requirement to use the web service. In general when you try to create code that runs on a web server you should use the object model or from remote you could use the client object model.

Comment: I need to hide columns in the form based on Groups. so using the webservice in the infopath form to hide or show columns based on sp group. (Yes, I am able to view the same groups in IE or Chrome using the same account).

Comment: To check if a user is in a group is to user the userprofile service. The following article describes how you an check if a user is member of a group http://www.projectpoint.at/?p=97